# AngularJS checkbox remove vlue when unchecked

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-core

So we have a shopping portal project, when we checked the checkbox it will plus the value in the cart, the problem is when we unchecked the checkbox it's still adding an item and we checked it again it will add again a value.

[image: picture of adding a other service]

```
     <input type="checkbox" id="{{p.productName}}" ng-checked="defaultCheckState"  ng-click="serviceAddOn(p);" />
```

I also tried this

```
     <input type="checkbox" id="{{p.productName}}" ng-checked="defaultCheckState" ng-true-value="serviceAddOn(p);" ng-false-value="Clear"/>
```

Angular code

```
     $scope.IsSavingAddOn = false;
    $scope.serviceAddOn = function (product) {
    $scope.IsSavingAddOn = true;
    $scope.total = $scope.qty * product.priceValue;
    //AddToCartService.AddToCart(product.productId, 'Service', $scope.qty, product.priceValue, $scope.total, true);
    $http.post("/Home/AddCart?productid=" + product.productId + "&subs=Service&qty=" + $scope.qty + "&unitprice=" + product.priceValue + "&amount=" + $scope.total)
        .then(function (response) {
        }).finally(function (response) {
            $scope.$emit('CountCartEvent');
            $scope.IsSavingAddOn = false;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng change and use if condition to check whether check box is checked or not

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{p.productName}}" ng-checked="defaultCheckState"  ng-change="serviceAddOn(p);" />

$scope.defaultCheckState = false;

$scope.serviceAddOn = function (product) {
    if(defaultCheckState){
        $scope.IsSavingAddOn = true;
        $scope.total = $scope.qty * product.priceValue;
        //AddToCartService.AddToCart(product.productId, 'Service', $scope.qty, product.priceValue, $scope.total, true);

        $http.post("/Home/AddCart?productid=" + product.productId + "&subs=Service&qty=" + $scope.qty + "&unitprice=" + product.priceValue + "&amount=" + $scope.total)
        .then(function (response) {
        }).finally(function (response) {
            $scope.$emit('CountCartEvent');
            $scope.IsSavingAddOn = false;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: the checkbox is disable I can't check it, and the name of the product become a code like this {{product.name}}

Comment: Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/ctreq?

Comment: add the `ng-model="defaultCheckState"` to the input